# changing the behavior of a command

Tags: macros

if `\foo{Complete}` compiles to

The Status: Complete

How can I change my LaTeX code so that `\foo{Complete}` compiles to

Status: Complete

This only needs to be changed in one place. I'm having trouble using renewcommand to do this. Does anybody know the correct tool?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  This seems to be a very theoretical question.  There is no guaranteed general way, depending on how `\foo` is defined. But in many cases you should just be able to do `\renewcommand{\foo}{Status: #1}`  Are you trying to change a specific command? If so, edit your question to include a minimal compilable document that shows what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

`\renewcommand` respects grouping:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{The Status: #1} % define \foo

\begin{document}

Some text, \foo{Complete}

More text, {\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{Status: #1}\foo{Complete}}

Some text, \foo{Complete}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better solution might be to define a *-variant, which gives even more flexibility, control and ease of code maintenance.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{S}{The s}tatus: #2%
}

\begin{document}

Some text, \foo{Complete}

More text, \foo*{Complete}

Some text, \foo{Complete}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{The Status: #1} % define \foo
\begin{document}
Some text, \foo{Complete}

\let\oldfoo\foo % save \foo as \oldfoo
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{Status: #1} % renew \foo
More text, \foo{Complete}

\let\foo\oldfoo % revert \foo to its original definition
and so on
\end{document}
```